# Is ip address unique to a user?

Tags: ip

I don't have a great understanding of how networking works. From what I understand the WAN ip address which is visible to the outside world is different from thed LAN ip address. Inspite of that at any point in time isn't an ip address unique to one particular user? The reason I ask this is because we get a lot of spam from one particular ipaddress. If we report that user to the authorities, without any trouble they should be able to pin point the user, correct? My guess is they can take this WAN address that we provide them, to the ISP provider. And the ISP provider will be able to link this WAN to a LAN ip address, which can pin point the spammer.

Comment: No. IPs are in no way whatsoever able to identify a particular user. Consider your average home dsl/cable router with a few computers, game consoles, tablets, and the neighbor's hacker kid freeloading on your wifi, all showing up as a single IP. then consider carrier grade NAT, where potentially thousands/millions of users show up as a single ip.

Answer (score 1):

Every host and a router on the Internet has an IP address, wich encodes its network number and host number. The combination is unique: in principle, no two machnies on the Internet have the same IP address. All IP Adresses are 32 bits long and are used in the Source address and Destination address fields of IP packets. You should note that an IP address does not actually refer to a host, but to a network interface, so if a host is on two networks, it must have two IP address, for example, if it is connected to local Ethernet, and to a WIFI(802.11) simultaneously. So, basically yes, you are correct, and the ISP provider should be able to locate it without difficulties.

EDIT: If the host is behind a NAT, then things can get a bit complicated, for example, if the user is spamming you from his office in a company, then that company gets the ip you are getting, but yet you are able to trace the company.